# Missing samples when using function plotProfile() from DiffBind for ATAC-seq

Tags: atac-seq

I have 4 samples which are 4 conditions but when I made this plot, I got only 2 conditions.

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```r
samples <- read.csv("path/to/sample_sheet_DiffBind.csv")
result <- dba(sampleSheet=samples)
result <- dba.blacklist(result) 
result <- dba.count(result, bParallel=FALSE)
result <- dba.normalize(result)
result <- dba.contrast(result, minMembers=2)
result <- dba.analyze(result)
dba.plotProfile(profiles)
```

I followed DiffBind manual but not sure why. Thank you so much! This is the plot before analyzing.

[image]